# Why would auto_prepend_file works in .htaccess but not in php.ini?

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-ini

So I'm using PHP's `auto_prepend_file` to load a config file I use. I tried doing it from php.ini but the file was never loaded. After some ... hours, I used .htaccess and voila, it works!

I'm using my own machine on windows 7 with wamp installed. The app is found under `D:\wamp\www\myawesomeapp` the global file (called config.php) is found at the root directory (I have some folders in there).

`auto_prepend_file = "D:\wamp\www\myawesomeapp\config.php"` did not work, however, adding `php_value auto_prepend_file D:/wamp/www/myawesomeapp/config.php` works perfectly fine.

Why? Shouldn't the config from php.ini just works? I also investigated include_path and added the app's folder just in case but still did not work.

Comment: Make sure you've updated the correct php.ini, __and__ restarted your web server

Comment: Have you tried using `/` instead `auto_prepend_file = "D:/wamp/www/myawesomeapp/config.php"`

Comment: @MarkBaker I ran `php.exe -i | grep php.ini` and it said that the loaded configuration file is the correct one: `D:\wamp\bin\php\phpversion\php.ini`

Comment: @LozCherone I tried both `/` and `\` .. didn't work.

Comment: If you run php.exe from the command line, then you see the php.ini file that's used by command line php; not by web php.... do a phpinfo() in a web page

Comment: @MarkBaker MY GOD! it's running a completely different ini file! It's running `D:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini`. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Ali - that's pretty normal; there's a lot of settings in php.ini where you do want to have different values for CLI and for web (e.g. timeout, memory), and others that only apply to web (post max size, session handling, etc)

Comment: @MarkBaker please write your answer so I could accept it and a side question: why is there is a php.ini in `apache` in the first place? there is a php.ini in php itself.

Comment: ummm, I'm using the correct php.ini file and now but the issue returned :-\.

Comment: Best people to answer that side question are the people that produce wampp - I work on Linux